# altering the add content type form

Tags: 7, forms, hooks

I am going to alter the form of `add content type form` and for that I used the `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`

Here is my code which implement in the module file, but it is not working.

```
function hc_listings_menu()
{
    $items = array();
    $items['node/add/home-care-popular-search-region']=array(
        'title' => 'Create Home Care Popular Search Region',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments'=> array('home_care_popular_search_region_node_form',''),
        'type'=>MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );
    return $items;
}
function hc_listing_home_care_popular_search_region_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)                                 
{

    $state_list=['ffff','gggg'];
    $region_list=['1','2','3','4'];
    $form['home_care_popular_search_region']=array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#default_value' => '',
        '#title' => t('Homeeee Care Popular Search Region'),
        '#description' => t('Home Care Popular Search Region'),
        '#required' => TRUE,

    );
    $form['hc_popular_state']=array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#default_value' => $state_list,
        '#title' => t('Popular State'),
        '#description' => t('Home Care Popular State'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['hc_popular_regions']=array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#default_value' => $region_list,
        '#title' => t('Popular Search Region'),
        '#description' => t('Home Care Popular Search Region'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );

}
```

**Note**: content type is => home_care_popular_search_region

module is => hc_listing

Should I have to remove the details in `hook_menu` regarding the altering?

Answer (score 0):

First, You need to find out the correct form id for this form and then you can use,

`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `hook_menu` from the module because there are not need to add this menu item.